# How to write parentheses for binary tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

Here I am trying to combine the binary tree into expression. For instance

b1 = BinaryTree(3.0)

print(parenthesize(b1))

3.0

b2 = BinaryTree(4.0)

b3 = BinaryTree(7.0)

b4 = BinaryTree("*", b1, b2)

b5 = BinaryTree("+", b4, b3)

print(parenthesize(b5))`

((3.0 * 4.0) + 7.0)

The code I write for `parenthesize()` is at the bottom and the above are the Binary tree base code. But my code, instead of returning "somenumber", it returns 
("somenumber"). When I delete the  "(", the parenthesizes totally disappeared. Could someone help fill the code?

```
class BinaryTree:
"""
A Binary Tree, i.e. arity 2.

=== Attributes ===
@param object data: data for this binary tree node
@param BinaryTree|None left: left child of this binary tree node
@param BinaryTree|None right: right child of this binary tree node
"""

def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
    """
    Create BinaryTree self with data and children left and right.

    @param BinaryTree self: this binary tree
    @param object data: data of this node
    @param BinaryTree|None left: left child
    @param BinaryTree|None right: right child
    @rtype: None
    """
    self.data, self.left, self.right = data, left, right

def __eq__(self, other):
    """
    Return whether BinaryTree self is equivalent to other.

    @param BinaryTree self: this binary tree
    @param Any other: object to check equivalence to self
    @rtype: bool

    >>> BinaryTree(7).__eq__("seven")
    False
    >>> b1 = BinaryTree(7, BinaryTree(5))
    >>> b1.__eq__(BinaryTree(7, BinaryTree(5), None))
    True
    """
    return (type(self) == type(other) and
            self.data == other.data and
            (self.left, self.right) == (other.left, other.right))

def __repr__(self):
    """
    Represent BinaryTree (self) as a string that can be evaluated to
    produce an equivalent BinaryTree.

    @param BinaryTree self: this binary tree
    @rtype: str

    >>> BinaryTree(1, BinaryTree(2), BinaryTree(3))
    BinaryTree(1, BinaryTree(2, None, None), BinaryTree(3, None, None))
    """
    return "BinaryTree({}, {}, {})".format(repr(self.data),
                                           repr(self.left),
                                           repr(self.right))

def __str__(self, indent=""):
    """
    Return a user-friendly string representing BinaryTree (self)
    inorder.  Indent by indent.

    >>> b = BinaryTree(1, BinaryTree(2, BinaryTree(3)), BinaryTree(4))
    >>> print(b)
        4
    1
        2
            3
    <BLANKLINE>
    """
    right_tree = (self.right.__str__(
        indent + "    ") if self.right else "")
    left_tree = self.left.__str__(indent + "    ") if self.left else ""
    return (right_tree + "{}{}\n".format(indent, str(self.data)) +
            left_tree)

def __contains__(self, value):
    """
    Return whether tree rooted at node contains value.

    @param BinaryTree self: binary tree to search for value
    @param object value: value to search for
    @rtype: bool

    >>> BinaryTree(5, BinaryTree(7), BinaryTree(9)).__contains__(7)
    True
    """
    return (self.data == value or
            (self.left and value in self.left) or
            (self.right and value in self.right))

def parenthesize(b):
"""
Return a parenthesized expression equivalent to the arithmetic
expression tree rooted at b.

Assume:  -- b is a binary tree
         -- interior nodes contain data in {'+', '-', '*', '/'}
         -- interior nodes always have two children
         -- leaves contain float data

@param BinaryTree b: arithmetic expression tree
@rtype: str

>>> b1 = BinaryTree(3.0)
>>> print(parenthesize(b1))
3.0
>>> b2 = BinaryTree(4.0)
>>> b3 = BinaryTree(7.0)
>>> b4 = BinaryTree("*", b1, b2)
>>> b5 = BinaryTree("+", b4, b3)
>>> print(parenthesize(b5))
((3.0 * 4.0) + 7.0)
"""
if b is None:
    return ''
else:
    return "("+parenthesize(b.left)+str(b.data)+parenthesize(b.right)+")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want your code to only place parentheses around nodes (trees) that have operations attached. In your comments you say that

```
b1 = BinaryTree(3.0)
print(parenthesize(b1))
# 3.0
```

But that isn't what is happening when you run your code. Instead the output is `(3.0)` this is introducing redundant parentheses when your node is part of a larger expression.

To correct the issue I added an `elif` clause to your function as shown below.

```
def parenthesize(b):
    if b is None:
        return ''
    elif b.left is None and b.right is None:
        return str(b.data)
    else:
        return "("+ parenthesize(b.left)+str(b.data) + parenthesize(b.right)+")
```

This produces the following output:

```
b1 = BinaryTree(3.0)
b2 = BinaryTree(4.0)
b3 = BinaryTree(7.0)
b4 = BinaryTree("*", b1, b2)
b5 = BinaryTree("+", b4, b3)
print(parenthesize(b5))
# ((3.0*4.0)+7.0)
```

Which I think is what you want. You may want to change the elif clause to check for only a single side being empty as opposed to both, but I don't know how you are going to use your code. For example, do you want a unary expression such as `3++` to be allowed? and if so do you want to enclose it in ()?